# "Many constitutional lawyers believe the court will rule it would be unlawful for Holyrood..."

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I'm stumbling upon the sentence:

"*Many constitutional lawyers believe the court will rule it would be unlawful for Holyrood and [...]*"

I understand it if :

- I translate *will* -> *wish to*, but I guess that *will* here is used to mark the future.
- or if I change the sentence with "*believe that if the court rule it*" (not "rules it" ?)

but "*will rule it would be unlawful*", is strange to me.

Can you explain me what I'm reading?

Comment: Does it make more sense if we just add *that*?  "Many constitutional lawyers believe **that** the court will rule..."

Comment: Do you know that "will" can mean future? That's all it means here. "*Lawyers believe the court **is going to** rule it would be unlawful...*"

Answer (score 1):

In this case "will" basically means "sometime in the future".

Rework the sentence as:
`Many constitutional lawyers believe the court, sometime in the future, rule it would be unlawful for Holyrood